# How to get a hover underline to appear above text and have a drop-shadow effect?

Tags: html, css

[image]

[image]

As you can see in the first image, I have the underline appear under the links which covers the red "hr" that runs across the page. I want to apply the same effect on the archives and categories links but with it appearing above.  I can't seem to find a way of doing it.  I looked up a hover underline position, and  tried using text-underline-position to being above but that doesn't do what I want it to do.  How do I go about doing this?

In the second image, in the prototype I had designed to have the underline have a drop-shadow effect.  How do I go about doing that with hover links?  Can it even be achieved if I'm using an image as a background? Or would I need to save that as a .png with transparency? Any tips?

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My Site</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" type="text/css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <header></header>

    <div id="NavSection">
      <div id="TopNav">
        <nav id="MainNav">
          <ul id="Menu">
            <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>

      <hr />

      <div id="SecondNavSection">
        <nav id="SecondNav">
          <ul id="SecondMenu">
            <li><a href="">Archives</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Categories</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>

      <div id="SiteTitle">
        <h1 id="My">My<span id="Site">Site</span></h1>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="ContentDiv">
      <main id="ContentSection">
        <div id="Content">
          <p>Content goes here.</p>
        </div>
      </main>
    </div>

    <footer>
      <p>My Site</p>
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  background: url(/images/background.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  resize: both;
  overflow: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0px;
  font-family: Arial;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: ubuntu-medium;
  src: url(/fonts/ubuntu-medium.ttf);
}

/* @media (max-width:3440px){
  body{background: url(/images/background.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;}
} */

/* @media (min-width:480px){
  body{background: url(/images/background.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;}
} */

#NavSection {
  margin-top: 3%;
}

#MainNav {
  position: left;
  margin-left: 11%;
}

#Menu li {
  font-family: ubuntu-medium;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #414141;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 15px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

#Menu a:hover {
  text-decoration-color: #414141;
  text-underline-offset: 0.12em;
  text-decoration-line: underline;
  text-decoration-style: solid;
  text-decoration-thickness: 4px;
}

hr {
  margin: 0px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  width: auto;
}

a {
  color: #414141;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:active {
  color: #ff0000;
}

#SiteTitle {
  margin-left: 0%;
}

#My {
  font-family: Impact;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-decoration-color: #414141;
  text-decoration-thickness: 2px;
  text-underline-offset: 0.08em;
}

#Site {
  color: red;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#SecondNav {
  float: right;
  font-family: ubuntu-medium;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #414141;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-right: 11%;
}

#SecondMenu a:hover {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  text-decoration-line: underline;
  text-underline-position: above;
  text-decoration-style: solid;
  text-decoration-color: #414141;
  text-decoration-thickness: 4px;
}

#SecondMenu li {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  font-family: ubuntu-medium;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #414141;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 15px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

#ContentDiv {
  width: 70%;
  height: 40%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  left: 15%;
  transform: translateX(0%);
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

#ContentSection {
  width: 90%;
  height: 60%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  left: 5%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
}

#Content {
  margin: 3%;
}
```

Comment: Wrap the link in a div and prepend a div on top that is just a solid rect.

Comment: Post your CSS and HTML of the above pictures.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

**HTML code**

```
<div class="menu">
<a href="#">A</a>
<a href="#">B</a>
<a href="#">C</a>
<a href="#">D</a>
<a href="#">E</a>
<a href="#">F</a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
    .body {
     background:#222; 
     padding:50px;
     }

    .menu {  
    margin:0 auto; 
    with 90%;
    }

    .menu a {
    display:block; 
    float: left; 
    padding:5px 0;
    color:#fff; 
    text-decoration:none;
    margin:0 10px; font-family:arial;
    }

   .menu a:hover { 
    border-bottom:3px solid #fff;
    }
```

Hope gonna help you, also i would be glad if you rate my comment good!

Answer (score 0):

Using two lists and using border on the li you can get the color.

```css
.navbar {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  font-family: ubuntu-medium;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.navbar a { 
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #414141;
}

.navbar ul {
    display: flex;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.navbar ul li {
    display: block;
    flex: 0 1 auto; /* Default */
    list-style-type: none;
    line-height: 2.5em;
    margin-left: 1em;
}

.sub ul {
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.navbar::before{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  margin-top: 2.5em;
  content: '';
  border-top: 10px solid #FF0000;
  width:100%;
}


.main li.active {
  border-bottom: 10px solid #000000;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 2px -2px #AAAAAA;
}

.sub li.active {
  border-top: 10px solid #000000;
  margin-top: -10px;
  box-shadow: 0px -4px 2px -2px #AAAAAA;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <nav class="main">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" class="active">Home</a></li>
      <li class="active"><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <nav class="sub">
    <ul>
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Bar</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Baz</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```